# Javascript change colour of divs, and then colour of the div's focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a html forum and am using javascript to change the colour of the forum, I have three divs, one is blue, green and red.

When each div is clicked, the **javascript will change the colour of the elements**.

I would like to change the colour of the submit button's focus with the .css() function in javascript, but **the focus part doesn't work**.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$("#green").click(function() {
    $(".mailheader").css("background","#a3d300");
    $(".submit").css("background","#a3d300");
    $(".submit:focus").css("background","#98cf00");
});
$("#blue").click(function() {
    $(".mailheader").css("background","#00b4ff");
    $(".submit").css("background","#00b4ff");
    $(".submit:focus").css("background","#04a6e9");
});
$("#red").click(function() {
    $(".mailheader").css("background","#ff0000");
    $(".submit").css("background","#ff0000");
    $(".submit:focus").css("background","#ea0202");
});
```

So I have tried `$(".submit:focus").css("background","#ea0202");` for chaning the background of the focus, but it doesn't work. anyone know how to fix this? thanks

Comment: What error are you getting in your browser console..?

Comment: There's no error, just the `$(".submit:focus").css("background","#ea0202");` line isn't changing the background colour for the focus of the submit button.

Comment: Change `background` to `background-color`

Comment: Can I suggest instead of setting the CSS using JavaScript you instead set a class on some parent element and then define your CSS in a style sheet. Replace your .click function with something like: $("body").addClass("green"); - I believe this may also fix your focus issue.

Comment: I already have a stylesheet, i'm just making it so if the user wants to change the colour of the form, they can do it easily through javascript

Comment: Yes you can still do that but keep all your CSS in a style sheet. Its much better for maintainability purposes. That is unless you want them to specify their own colours.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, +1 vote for all answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check this**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T373H/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="mailheader"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<input type="button" value="submit" class="submit" />
```

**CSS**

```
#green, #red, #blue {
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
}
#green {
    background-color:green;
}
#red {
    background-color:red;
}
#blue {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#green").click(function () {
    $(".mailheader").css("background", "#a3d300");
    $(".submit").css("background", "#a3d300");
    $(".submit").focus(function () {
        $(".submit").css("background", "#04a6e9");
    })
});
$("#blue").click(function () {
    $(".mailheader").css("background", "#00b4ff");
    $(".submit").css("background", "#00b4ff");
    $(".submit").focus(function () {
        $(".submit").css("background", "#ea0202");
    })
});
$("#red").click(function () {
    $(".mailheader").css("background", "#ff0000");
    $(".submit").css("background", "#ff0000");
    $(".submit").focus(function () {
        $(".submit").css("background", "#98cf00");
    })
});
```

Comment: This works, but with css when you focus on the div, it will change colour, and when you click on something else, it will go to the normal colour. How would you do that for this, like when you 'unfocus' the button it goes back to normal colour? Thanks

Comment: I found out that I can use .blur() to do this, thanks for the answer tho, i'll make it the accepted answer

Comment: I think using `.focus()` for a button err~... is not a good idea, since using js for buttons is hard(tiny bit) for computers and the css doesn't change back. :(

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can't change pseudo-elements' style

Fix (I used the `.html()` function for the `:focus`'s style, using a `<style>` tag in the body or elsewhere):

```
<script>
    ...
    $(".submit").css("background","#ff0000");
    $("body style.changeColor").html("
        .submit:focus {background: #ea0202};
    ");
    ...
</script>
<body>
    <style class="changeColor">
    </style>
</body>
```

And I were you, I rather change all other `.css()` functions into text inside the `.html()` string.

```
$("body style.changeColor").html("
    ...
    .submit {background: #ff0000};
    .submit:focus {background: #ea0202};
");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting styles directly on the element. Why not set a css class on the elements and handle all the changes via css. That is much cleaner and easier to use.

eg. when '#green' is clicked add a class 'Green' to the submit button. (see http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ ) (be sure to remove the other classes)

Then in css you can set #MySubmitButton.Green{.. your green styles..} and use all the pseudo css classes you like. Things like #MySubmitButton.Green:hover {color:#FF00FF;}

Hope this helps...